# Javascript switch statement with wildcard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wildcard, switch-statement

If my javascript ajaxes away to my server and returns an ID of `49` in the plain text format of `[49]` is there a way in which i an do something like this... (i have tested and doesnt work)

```
switch(data)
{
    case '[*]':
        (..etc.)
    break;
}
```

Where the wildcard is the `*` and i want to make sure it is enclosed within two square parenthesis?

Because i need to check that there wasnt another word returned like `error` and i am reserving the `default` for unexpected errors, any ideas? :) Thanks!

Comment: @Tracker1's answer should really be the correct one considering the title of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `if else` and `regex` for matching wildcard patterns.

Assuming `data = "[49]";` or any digits inside brackets.

```
if(/\[\d+\]/.test(data)){
    //do something
}else{
    //default
}
```

Comment: i just saved the data to a var and then set the data to something else  if it was correct ;) cheers

Answer (score 17):

You can do a switch on true explicitely, which will use evaluation on each case statement.

```
switch (true) {
    case ((/^\[\d+\]$/).test(data)):
       //matches data;
       break;
    case (data == "something else"):
       //...
       break;
    default:
       //...
}
```

However, if you have less than say 4-5 cases, it would be better to use if/else if/else if/else blocks.

```
if ((/^\[\d+\]$/).test(data)) {
       //matches data;
} else if (data == "something else") {
       //...
} else {
       //...
}
```

I usually do some error trapping in my response methods for service/rest calls so that I almost always return a proper json with an error property if there is an error.

```
try {
  if (response.responseText.indexOf("<html") >= 0) { 
    throw response.responseText;
  }

  var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
  if (data.error) 
    throw data.error;

  //handle response data object.
  if ((/^\[\d+\]$/).test(data)) {
    //matches data;
  } else if (data == "something else") {
    //...
  } else {
    //...
  }
} catch(err) {
  if (err && err.message) {
      //use err.message
  } else if (err && err.toString().indexOf("<html") >= 0) {
      //handle error text
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of patterns and associated callbacks and do a simple loop and check for matches. For example:

```
    var patterns = [];

    function myCallback(){ document.write('myCallback!'); }
    function myOtherCallback(){ document.write('myOtherCallback!'); }
    function myLastCallback(){ document.write('You will never see me!'); }

    patterns.push({'pattern':new RegExp(/\[.+\]/),'callback': myCallback});
    patterns.push({'pattern':new RegExp(/.+/),'callback':myOtherCallback});
    patterns.push({'pattern':new RegExp(/A-Z{3}/),'callback':myLastCallback});

    var f = "[49]";
    for(var i=0;i<patterns.length;i++){
        if(patterns[i].pattern.test(f)){
            patterns[i].callback();
        }
    }
```

Which outputs the following:

```
myCallback!myOtherCallback!
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, switch/case can't handle wildcard.

You should probably do some preprocessing/sanity checking before entering the switch, or simply discard it completely since it's more appropriate for specific case scenarios rather than processing streamlined data. Regexp will serve you better here.

Comment: Yes, it can, see my prior post... actually it can handle true for the switch, then evaluate each case.  it doesn't have to be fixed values like case statements in other languages.

Comment: woot! nice one, didn't know about that.